# What does it mean "unique" for this author?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying Hungerford's *Abstract Algebra* book. I would like to know what the author means by "unique" in this theorem:

[image]

The orders count? I mean the element $g\in G$ such that $g=a_{i_1}a_{i_2}=a_{i_2}a_{i_1}$ is considered unique?

I'm asking that because we know that if $G$ is an internal weak direct product of the family $\{N_i\mid i\in I\}$, we have $a_{i_k}a_{i_l}=a_{i_l}a_{i_k}$ for every $a_{i_k}\in N_{i_k}$ and $a_{i_l}\in N_{i_l}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unique as in literally one and only one way to write it with those conditions, including the order.  That's why he doesn't allow any of them to be $e$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant so for the author the element $g$ I mentioned is not unique?

Comment: I see what you mean if $G$ is abelian.  But by order I really meant the correspondence between the elements and the $N_{i_k}$'s to which they belong.  In other words what is unique is that each $a_{i_k}$ is in $N_{i_k}$.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't answer your question very well.

Comment: What he means is if $g$ can be written as a product of $a_{i_k}$'s which $a_{i_k}\in N_{i_k}$ and $g'$ can be written as a product of $a'_{i_k}$'s which $a'_{i_k}\in N_{i_k}$, then $a'_{i_k}=a_{i_k}$ for all $i_k$.

Comment: Think about what happens in an actual direct sum.  Every element of the sum can be written uniquely as a sum of elements from subgroups (the embeddings of the components).  This is the condition he's trying to formalize to the general group.

Comment: @GregoryGrant He means more than that, in that also if you have two different subcollections (as sets) $\{i_1, \ldots, i_k\}$ and $\{j_1, \ldots, j_\ell\}$ of normal subgroups you are choosing nonidentity elements from, then you can't have $a_{i_1}\cdots a_{i_k} = b_{j_1}\cdots b_{j_\ell}$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thank you very much, you really helped me a lot!

Comment: In any case I commend you for reading Hungerford, which in my opinion is an incredibly good book on the subject.

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes, I know that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It's not written very clearly, but actually the order is intended not to matter because pairs of elements of two normal subgroups which intersect only at the identity in fact *must* commute, as you say:

Suppose $N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $N_1 \cap N_2 = \{e\}$. Then let $a \in N_1$ and $b \in N_2$. Then $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = (aba^{-1})b^{-1} \in N_2$ but also $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = a(ba^{-1}b^{-1}) \in N_1$, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$, or in other words $ab = ba$.

[Here's](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~hjlai/Teaching/Math541-641/1-5GroupProduct.pdf) a nice write-up I found on internal weak direct products with a more clearly stated characterization which you may find helpful.

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm going to read this article. Thanks again.